# Only take from the latest string with python regex

Tags: python, regex, linux, string, python-2.7

I using regex in my Python application.

The string that I run on with regex contains many lines.

String (a portion of the string i using):

```
 36% [============>                      ]  55.5 /  86.2 M   426.62 K   1m14s
 36% [============>                      ]  55.5 /  86.2 M   426.62 K   1m14s
 36% [============>                      ]  55.5 /  86.2 M   426.62 K   1m14s
 36% [============>                      ]  55.5 /  86.2 M   426.62 K   1m14s
 36% [============>                      ]  55.8 /  86.2 M   278.57 K   1m52s
 36% [============>                      ]  55.8 /  86.2 M   278.57 K   1m52s
 36% [============>                      ]  55.8 /  86.2 M   278.57 K   1m52s
 36% [============>                      ]  56.2 /  86.2 M   426.19 K   1m12s
 36% [============>                      ]  56.2 /  86.2 M   426.19 K   1m12s
 36% [============>                      ]  56.2 /  86.2 M   426.19 K   1m12s
 36% [============>                      ]  56.7 /  86.2 M   504.32 K   1m 0s
 36% [============>                      ]  56.7 /  86.2 M   504.32 K   1m 0s
 36% [============>                      ]  56.7 /  86.2 M   504.32 K   1m 0s
 36% [============>                      ]  57.1 /  86.2 M   409.67 K   1m13s
 36% [============>                      ]  57.1 /  86.2 M   409.67 K   1m13s
 36% [============>                      ]  57.1 /  86.2 M   409.67 K   1m13s[2K
 36% [============>                      ]  57.6 /  86.2 M   453.01 K   1m 5s[2K
 36% [============>                      ]  57.6 /  86.2 M   453.01 K   1m 5s
```

The string comes from a file.

I using this (Python) regex:

```
(.*%) (.*) (.*) / (.*) (M) (.*) (.*)
```

When I take the data from re (Python regex library) then only print data from the first line.

I want the data from the last line.

**More details:**

I using GNU/Linux and Python version 2.7.5

Comment: Not the problem you're asking about, but `.` matches anything but a newline. That includes spaces. Are you sure your regex captures what you want?

Comment: You could just add the end of line `$` anchor. `last = re.search(r'(.*%) (.*) (.*) / (.*) (M) (.*) (.*)$', s).group()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you want the data from the last line, and you're using a regex. So, you should first remove every content that you don't want from your string.

Let's define the `content` variable as:

```
 content = '36% [============>                      ]  55.5 /  86.2 M   426.62 K   1m14s
 36% [============>                      ]  55.5 /  86.2 M   426.62 K   1m14s
 36% [============>                      ]  55.5 /  86.2 M   426.62 K   1m14s
 [...]'
```

In that case, you should do `content.splitlines()[-1]` to get the last line and apply your regex on it. This method has two benefits:

1. You'll get the result expected.
2. It'll be faster, because the regex will be execute on a smaller string.

Comment: I ran your solution, but there was no data, the result was '' of split.

Comment: Try with `splitlines()` instead of `split('\n')`. Are you sure that there's \n in your string?

Answer (score 0):

You only show 3 literals in your regex, `%`,`/`, and `M`.
If the parenths are removed, your regex becomes `.*%.*.*/.*M.*.*`
which reduces to `.*%.*/.*M.*`.

If you just want the last line with `%`,`/`, and `M` in it, change it to

`(?-s).*%.*/.*M.*\s*$`

The `(?-s)` modifier insures the Dot does not match newlines (usually the default).
And, make sure to *Not* use the Multi-Line modifier (usually the default)
this way the `$` means end of string.

Add your groups to capture what you want.